# Android: change status bar position

Tags: android, android-statusbar

Within the development of an app for an android device (not a mobile device), it would be great if the status bar could be manipulated and placed on another position other than the top of the screen.

Is that possible?.

Comment: By Status bar, do you mean the bar that shows the notification or the Actionbar?

Comment: well, i mean the one with the battery, the mobile network signal strength, the wifi...etc

Comment: AFAIK that is the part of an app called SystemUI.apk which is part of the AOSP. If you have access to that, and are cool with that then, yes, you can. In fact it pretty straightforward there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since from the beginning of android , you cannot re-position the status bar , there is no official support

Although you can [hide it](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)